# Hide Numbers when category is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Kindly take a look at following fiddle in which i tried to remove the categories but on removing categories its placing numbers instead of it by default and also showing those numbers in tooltip.

All I am trying to do is that categories or numbers doesnot display on chart or on tooltip and only stackedbar appears on the chart , So kindly let me know how can i do it .Thanks,

http://jsfiddle.net/EJFsH/3/

```
$(function () {

    var data = [ {
        name: 'Year 2008',
        data: [0, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
    }];

    data = $.grep(data, function (category) {
        return $.grep(category.data, function (item) {
            return item > 0;
        }).length > 0;
    });


    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
        },
        xAxis: {

            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -100,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: data
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what you are asking for.  But, to turn off the XAxis or yAxis labels, juse labels : {enabled:false}  and to change the tooltips use tooltip:{formatter: function() {...}}

see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6ypq4/

```
xAxis: {

    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels : {
        enabled: false
    }
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Population (millions)',
        align: 'high'
    },
    labels: {
        overflow: 'justify',
        enabled: false
    }
},
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
            return this.y + ' millions';
    }
},
```